# Error setting up Sauce Connect - Sauce Labs: Error checking overlapping tunnels

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, saucelabs

Tried setting up sauce connect, but get an error.

Details below:

(I also tried opening ports 443 (outbound), 80, 60, 4445 (inbound) - but nothing changed)

I run :

> bin/sc -u [USERNAME] -k [KEY]

And Get:

```
>  15 Nov 18:30:42 - Sauce Connect 4.4.1, build 958 c1c1e98-dirty
>         15 Nov 18:30:42 - Starting up; pid 19768
>         15 Nov 18:30:42 - Command line arguments: C:\Users\[folder]\Desktop\sauce-connect\bin\sc.exe -u [username]
>         15 Nov 18:30:42 - Log file: /tmp/sc.log
>         15 Nov 18:30:42 - Pid file: C:\Users\[folder]\AppData\Roaming/sc_client.pid
>         15 Nov 18:30:42 - Timezone: Eastern Standard Time GMT OFfset: -5h
>         15 Nov 18:30:42 - Using no proxy for connecting to Sauce Labs REST API.
>         15 Nov 18:30:42 - Resolving saucelabs.com to 162.222.75.243 took 5 ms.
>         15 Nov 18:31:16 - Started scproxy on port 17809.
>         15 Nov 18:31:16 - Please wait for 'you may start your tests' to start your tests.
>         15 Nov 18:31:16 - Starting secure remote tunnel VM...
>         15 Nov 18:31:48 - GET https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/[username]/tunnels?full=1: Timeout was
> reached.
>         15 Nov 18:31:48 - Error checking overlapping tunnels.
>         15 Nov 18:31:48 - Cleaning up.
>         15 Nov 18:31:48 - Sauce Connect could not establish a connection.
>         15 Nov 18:31:48 - Please check your firewall and proxy settings.
>         15 Nov 18:31:48 - You can also use sc --doctor to launch Sauce Connect in diagnostic mode.
>         15 Nov 18:31:48 - Goodbye.
```